# How do I download source files, which are linked in gerrit via C# programmatically?

Tags: c#, gerrit, gitweb

I am newly beginning developer in android;
btw after I log in into my gerrit, I can see my git commit changes and some source files those are changed.

As you know after clicking the side by side link right side of the source's list,
I can enter web based diff site, where I can really easy to see the differences.
ok
here is the spot, where my real problem begins.
I want to make a program that takes permalink,
that downloads before and after versions of source which are returned as a zip file by gerrit server (after clicking download image in diff page).
I really tried to download via C# using various ways, including SHDocVw, WebBrowser and so on...but still i dont get it.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: check out the query functionality: http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3021/documentation/2.1.4/cmd-query.html

Comment: Is it really important to get it as a zip file, as you can get the information by using the checkout functionality in the Patch Set section on the "frontpage" of the change, then you can do the diffing locally in your workarea